# Buttons toggle in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a toggle button component with two buttons, where clicking on one disables the other and vice versa. I have a disabled state I know I have to toggle. But I'm not sure how to pan out the logic. Should there be one disabled state or two since there are two buttons?

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { disabled: false }
    }

clicky(e) {
  //should dictate the toggle logic
}

render () {
  <div onClick={this.clicky.bind(this)}>
    <button disabled={this.state.disabled}>Item 1</button>
    <button disabled={this.state.disabled}>Item 2</button>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I think you should have two disabled state , or you can just have one state to save which button is avaliable

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping a boolean, you would keep the button identifier in the disabled state, which can scale upto any number of buttons instead of just two

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { disabled: "1" }
}

clicky(e) {
  //should dictate the toggle logic
  const id = e.target.id
  this.setState({ disabled: id })
}

render () {
  <div onClick={this.clicky.bind(this)}>
    <button disabled={this.state.disabled === "1"} id="1">Item 1</button>
    <button disabled={this.state.disabled === "2"} id="2">Item 2</button>
  </div>
}
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wk706w4w6w)**

Comment: Using ids in react components isn't recommended as you can't reuse the component (or shouldn't anyways). A better method would be to use a data-prop, or a ref.

Comment: @AnilRedshift you can always reuse the component, you just to to change the id as you would change your data-props. In fact a button can become a component itself and get the id as a prop from the parent and use it

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { button1Disabled: false }
}

clicky() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    button1Disabled: !prevState.button1Disabled
  }));
}

render () {
  return (
    <div onClick={this.clicky.bind(this)}>
      <button disabled={this.state.button1Disabled}>Item 1</button>
      <button disabled={!this.state.button1Disabled}>Item 2</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you end up with clicking the button multiple times before the next paint comes through

Comment: @AnilRedshift, not true. His solution is perfectly fine. You won't ever get what you are describing with this solution.

Comment: @Dane, you did forget to negate the previous value though with `!` in your setState.

Comment: @Chris: Consider that you mash button1 multiple times. In react, there is no guarantee that the render happens immediately, especially with upcoming fibers. So what happens is that you end up toggling the state back and forth, but what you really should be doing is disabling item 1, no matter how many times it's clicked

Comment: click event, click event, click event, click event.... this all batches and then asynchronously the `clicky` is called. The expected behavior should be that button 1 is disabled no matter how many times you click it

Comment: @AnilRedshift, `setState` from **separate** event handlers cannot batch, so this won't ever happen. But even if they did batch, using the functional `setState` actually guarantees that they will be queued rather than batched. Passing an object in instead is what can get the updates batched (if we were talking about `setState` within the same handler, but this isn't the case here).

Answer (score 1):

Dane has the best answer (in my opinion) so far, and my answer is quite similar to his. Though I do want to make some further suggestions:

- First one would be to move the event listener out of your div and attach it to each of your buttons. The main reason being improving accessibility (e.g for screen readers) because static elements such as `div`, `p`, etc don't have a semantic meaning. Besides, it kind of makes more sense to have the actual button trigger something, rather than the buttons wrapper.
- My second suggestion is to move your binding of your `clicky()` function into the constructor instead. This will prevent your component from binding on each re-render and will instead only do so once on component mount.

Here is a slighly modified version of Danes solution:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { button1Disabled: false }
  this.clicky = this.clicky.bind(this);
}

clicky() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    button1Disabled: !prevState.button1Disabled
  }));
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.clicky} disabled={this.state.button1Disabled}>Item 1</button>
      <button onClick={this.clicky} disabled={!this.state.button1Disabled}>Item 2</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the buttons are inversely related, one state is a better idea, because with two variables, they can get out of sync. Also, because only one button is enabled at a time, managing state is simple, you just need to toggle the state every time a button is clicked:

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.item1 = React.createRef();
     this.item2 = React.createRef();
     this.state = { enableFirst: true }
   }

clicky(e) {
  const enableFirst = e.target !== item1;
  this.setState({ enableFirst });
}

render () {
 <div onClick={this.clicky.bind(this)}>
   <button ref={item1} disabled={this.state.enableFirst}>Item 1</button>
   <button ref={item2} disabled={!this.state.enableFirst}>Item 2</button>
 </div>
}
```

Comment: How would they get out of sync?